# Repeat the same word over and over in menu

Tags: usability, wording

I have a menu with a list of a lot of management and configuration GUIs. They are listed below a headline of the category. Like so:

**Managemanet**

Xxxxxx Management

Xxxx Management

Xxxxxxxx Management

Xxxxx Management

Xxxxxxxxxx Management

**Configuration**

Xxxxxxxxx Configuration

Xxxx Configuration

Xxxxxx Configuration

Xxxxx Configuration

Xxxxxxxx Configuration

My question is: 
Do I have to repeat each word in the menu or is it enough to let the headline do that job?

When the user clicks on a link he will go to that GUI and see the headline, which will be the full name, i.e. Xxxxxxxx Configuration (not just Xxxxxxxx). Do you think the non-consistency will cause confusion?

Comment: Can you give some examples of these Xxxxxxx terms?

Comment: Rule Configuration, Account Configuration, Priority Configuration.... If I were to skip the configuration part it would be Rules, Accounts and Priorities

Comment: I think the confusion comes in a step earlier than that: what's the difference between "management" and "configuration"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the labeling away from what the option is towards what the option *does* - and therefore what it *enables the user to do*, then it can become much simpler.

[image: Menu with verb-noun structures]

Comment: Hi! Good input! Thank you! I'm just worried that the user might be confused when the links name is Configure: Rules, and the the main title of the GUI is Rule Configuration. Do you think this will be a problem?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem unless it's 'stand out different' to everything else in your app. The menu option 'Configure: Rules' is a call to action and takes you to an appropriately named place 'Rule configuration' - that's ok. But actually - why *not* name the GUI with 'Configure rules' ? It's a bit like a menu on my browser - it says 'Bookmark all tabs...' and takes me to a dialog of the same name - not 'Tab bookmarking'. I should add that if it's going to *take you* somewhere rather than just *do* something then you want an ellipsis after rules..., accounts..., priorities....

Answer (score 5):

Lets take this example - Say there is a menu item with broad heading: **Shoes**. So, the items inside will read Formal Shoes, Slippers, Kids' Shoes etc. and not just Formal, Slippers, Kids'. However if you changes the headline to say, **Choose by Shoe type** - then having items like Formals, Slippers, Kids are acceptable and make sense. So the esscence is that the heading label and it being a noun/verb justifies for the  connection between the heading and the items.

Given the scenario at hand, this is what I would suggest:

1) If you have to use heading as "Configuration", then it makes sense to use Rule Configuration, Account Configuration, Priority Configuration etc as items. Imagine without the configuration word, the user reading it as Configuration-Rules, which is not how they are used to pronounce/know it. I understand the repetitiveness but removing it altogether could lead to confusions/extra effort. You could also change the header to read: **Configuration Categories** or something, so that the effect of repeatedness tones downs a little.

2) Another solution could be a change in the heading label. Say, if you could make it something like - **Choose Configuration Category**, then having Rules, Accounts etc might make sense.

Comment: I agree with Amit, simply put the main title as heading, Configuring Options, Management Options or Configure and Manage